# How to create an infinite Table of numbers

Tags: equation-solving

I wish to create to generate the set $\{\pm \, 5^n : n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \}$ and solve the equation $a+b =c+d$ for all elements quadruplets $a,b,c,d$ in the set which satisfy it.

How would I go about this problem. I know how to use the Table and Solve commands in general but not in this particular case

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
n = 70;
Do[If[5^a + 5^b == 5^c + 5^d, Print[{a, b, c, d}]], {a, 0, n}, {b, 
  a + 1, n}, {c, b + 1, n}, {d, c + 1, n}]
```

of course, $70\ll\infty$
but I am quite confident that the only solutions are
$$a=c, b=d\\a=d, b=c.$$

Comment: If I changed 5 to another prime, say 2, would I get the same result

Comment: @Jaunemoto Go ahead: try it yourself and see!

Comment: The case where base is 2 is a little different because `2^n+2^n=2^(n+2)-2^(n+1)`. For base of 3 there is `3*n+3^n=3^(n+1)-3^n`. For prime bases larger than 3 the growth is too large to allow for nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Say $a=\pm 5^{n_a},b=\pm 5^{n_b},c=\pm 5^{n_c}$ and $d=\pm 5^{n_d}$ and that WLOG $n_a$ is the smallest. Then
$$5^{n_b-n_a}\pm 1=\pm 5^{n_c-n_a}\pm 5^{n_d-n_a}.$$

The right hand side is divisible by 5 unless $n_a=n_d$ or $n_a=n_c$, and the LHS is not, unless $n_a=n_b$. So the only solutions are

$$(a,b,c,d)=(\pm 5^{n_1},\mp 5^{n_1},\pm 5^{n_2},\mp5^{n_2}),$$
or
$$(a,b,c,d)=(\pm 5^{n_1},\pm 5^{n_2},\pm 5^{n_2},\pm 5^{n_1}),$$
or
$$(a,b,c,d)=(\pm 5^{n_1},\pm 5^{n_2},\pm 5^{n_1},\pm 5^{n_2}).$$

Comment: Thanks. How could I solve it if I replaced 5 with another prime, say 2?